# How do I disable code from running in the development environment on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dev-to-production

How can I remove code when my Rails app is in development mode? For example, I want to remove my Google Analytics reference when in development but have it render in the production environment.

Is there a solution that con be implemented in the views or the controllers? I can see a need for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<% if Rails.env == 'production' %>
  ...production code goes here...
<% end %>
```

This works for Rails 3. In older versions, user the environment variable RAILS_ENV.

Robin

Comment: Thanks, Robin. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A shorter way: if Rails.env.production?